# Get parent from parent node in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html code:
[image: products]

when I click on the Delete button the < li > attribute from that product must delete.

It had worked with JS but now it fails to do so.
The listener:

```
cartList.on('click', '.delete-item', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  removeProduct($(event.target).parents('.product'));
});
```

This is the removeproduct function till where it crashes:

```
function removeProduct(product) {
  clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
  cartList.find('.deleted').remove();
  var topPosition = product.offset().top - cartBody.children('ul').offset().top, 
    productQuantity = Number(product.find('.quantity').find('input').val()),
    productTotPrice = Number(product.find('.price').text().replace('€', ''));
}
```

I get the error:

> main.js:168 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

So probably he can't get the node product but reads only "actions" - the first node as parent. But how can i acces the product li attribute to delete the whole row

Comment: `cartBody.children('ul').offset()` is `undefined`. What is `cartBody`? Does it have any child `ul` elements?

Comment: If you have HTML to show in a question please include it as text, not a picture, so that (where relevant) people can easily copy it into their answers.

Comment: the html is with javascript encoded

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   var cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body');

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container');

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below snippet:

```
cartList.on('click', '.delete-item', function(event){
 $(this).parents('.product').remove(); //this will remove the parent .product from the DOM
});
```

Comment: it removes indeed. Do you know how I get the "productQuantity" out of it, doesn't work now..

Comment: productQuantity = Number(product.find('.quantity').find('input').val()), there is no input tag inside the div "quantity".